# Why does רע"ב on עירובין א י not simply say the הלכה is like רבי יהודה?

Tags: mishna, maseches-eruvin, bartenura

When discussing if you can make partitions using only קנים (vertical sticks), the משנה and גמרא record 4 opinions. My understanding of the 4 opinions is here:
[image]

The ריטב"א comment is based on [this linked source](https://www.sefaria.org/Ritva_on_Eruvin.17a.4?vhe=Chidushi_HaRitva,_Amsterdam,_1729.&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he).

What confused me was [רע"ב](https://www.sefaria.org/Bartenura_on_Mishnah_Eruvin.1.10.4?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)'s comments as to the הלכה, appended in the chart with [הלכה] at in two places:

> אחד משני דברים. או שתי או ערב ואיכא בין רבנן קמאי לרבנן בתראי דרבנן קמאי לא שרו ליחיד אלא דומיא דשיירא, בדרך, הואיל ואינו יכול לעשות מחיצה ראויה, ולא בישוב, ורבנן בתראי אמרי אחד משני דברים בין ליחיד בין לרבים בין בדרך בין בישוב, **והלכתא כותייהו. אלא שאדם אחד או שנים ששבתו במדבר אין יכולים לעשות מחיצה גדולה יותר מבית סאתים** שהוא מאה אמה אורך על חמשים רוחב כחצר המשכן, ושלשה בני אדם או יותר הן שיירא ויכולים לעשות מחיצה גדולה ואפילו כמה מילין כפי מה שצריך להם ולכלי תשמישם ולבהמתם, ובלבד שלא ישאר מקום פנוי בתוך המחיצה יותר מבית סאתים:

Why does רע"ב say the הלכה is like חכמים ב in a שירא but also that only 2 סאה are allowed in a smaller group - why not just simpler, that the הלכה is like רבי יהודה, since that describes how he holds in both cases?

Edit: To answer comment's question - how do I know רבי יהודה holds in groups (בשירא) all space is allowed (כל צרכן), I'm not 100% clear. But Artscroll's footnote 24. on 17a summarizes the opinions and says this explicitly. And ריטב"א's proof (linked above) to the חכמים agreeing is ובשיירא אפילו רבנן קמאי מודו דאפילו ביישוב נותנין להם כל צרכן וכדאמרי׳ בהדיא דיחיד ביישוב בלחוד איכא בינייהו. It seems to me that the same דיוק could be made on the גמרא, where רבי יהודה says something [similar](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.16b.21?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) מַקִּיפִין בְּקָנִים וְכוּ׳. בִּשְׁיָרָא אִין, בְּיָחִיד לָא? וְהָתַנְיָא, רַבִּי יְהוּדָה אוֹמֵר: כׇּל מְחִיצּוֹת שַׁבָּת לֹא הִתִּירוּ לְיָחִיד יוֹתֵר מִבֵּית סָאתַיִם.

Comment: How do you know that Rabbi Yehuda allows *kanim* for a space up to 2 *seah*? The simple reading of the mishnah is that it is not allowed for any space...

Comment: @JoelK great question, I thought about that a lot. I edited my question, let me know if It's not clear enough.

Comment: My point was more about Rabbi Yehuda in the case of 1 or 2 people. Nowhere in the mishnah, or Bartenura up till now, does it say that Rabbi Yehuda allows *kanim* for 1 or 2 people if the space is less than 2 *se'ah*.

Comment: I think that's explicitly in a ברייתא in the גמרא, quoted in the edit וְהָתַנְיָא, רַבִּי יְהוּדָה אוֹמֵר: כׇּל מְחִיצּוֹת שַׁבָּת לֹא הִתִּירוּ לְיָחִיד יוֹתֵר מִבֵּית סָאתַיִם. When it says "יותר מבית סאתים" that implies up to בית סאתים is מותר.

Comment: That could very well be true, but if I'm learning mishna with Bartenura I don't necessarily know that. If he tells me הלכה כרבי יהודה, I will not know what the halacha actually is

Comment: Okay, fair point, that may be the answer. Though I guess I expected a comment at the end "and this is the opinion of רבי יהודה", but the Bartenura doesn't say everything.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Ovadiah of Bertinoro was 15th century and likely did not come up with this on his own, to say in Aramaic והלכתא כותייהו. Rather, he's channeling an earlier source such as the Rif, in the 11th century, who [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.16b.22?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&p2=Rif_Eruvin.5a.3&lang2=bi&w2=Eruvin&lang3=en) in quite similar language:

> וחכמים אומרים אחד משני דברים: חכמים היינו תנא קמא איכא בינייהו יחיד בישוב דרבנן בתראי סברי יחיד בישוב שרי לטלטולי בתוך מחיצה של שתי או של ערב כדין המדבר **והלכתא כוותיהו** :

The Rif operates by quoting the Mishnah and important excerpts of the gemara, then says when we rule like them. I don't feel like delving into how Rabbi Yehuda particularly holds (according to Ritva), which might be subject to dispute amongst Rishonim, but the reason we hold "like them" in this presumably something like ruling like the majority instead of the individual. Even if eventually, some combination / configuration led to a Rabbi Yehuda-expounded position, that is not the decisive principle that led the Rif to rule as he did, as he processed the gemara.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the חידושי הגר"א מגריידיץ (from in the קובץ מפרשים of the עוז והדר משניות) addresses this point:

> **חידושי הגר"א מגריידיץ רע"ב ד"ה אחד משני דברים.** והלכתא כוותיהו וכו'. הרע"ב קיצר כאן, דלכאורה נראה כסותר את דבריו שאמר בין ליחיד בין לרבים וכו' שהשוה יחיד לרבים, והדר כתב אלא שאדם אחד וכו' [שהוא כדעת רבי יהודה במתני' כדמתרץ הגמ' (טז:) לא נצרכה וכו', ועיין רש"י שם ד"ה ליתן וכו' דהא דקאמר רבי יהודה וכו']. ...

He says the רע"ב words are very abbreviated, because taken literally they contradict themselves - the 1st "הלכתא כותייהו" implies both an individual and group can have כל צרכן, and then he qualifies it.

The rest of the comment of the חידושי הגר"א מגריידיץ appears to be clarifying the different opinions and what is the הלכה.